# problem with jquery autocomplete and zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I am trying to implement [this](http://www.rojakcoder.com/wordpress/2009/01/08/using-zend-framework-with-jquery-to-do-auto-completion/) tutorial in my application. I have managed to make it work until the point where I had to modify the view controller and add the link to the .ajax.html file.

My code so far:

```
 class MenuController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

        public function init() {
            $this->_helper->ajaxContext()->addActionContext('addRecipe', 'html')->initContext();
            parent::init();
     }

              public function addRecipeAction() {
            if ($this->_helper->ajaxContext()->getCurrentContext()) {
                $this->view->words = array('leon', 'lionel', 'Lenny', 'Linda', 'Lindy');
            }

            $recipeForm = new Application_Form_Recipe();
            $recipeForm->setMethod('post');
            $recipeForm->setAction('/menu/add-recipe');
            $this->view->recipeForm = $recipeForm;
        }
        }
```

The add-recipe.ajax.phtml file:

```
<?php
foreach ($this->words as $word) {
    echo "{$word}\n";
}
?>
```

The view file add-recipe.phtml

```
<?php

echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/jquery.autocomplete.css');
$this->jQuery()->enable();
$this->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('/js/jquery/js/jquery.autocomplete.js');

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#username').autocompleteArray('http://bucatarie/menu/add-recipe/format/html');
    });
</script>


<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
```

For some strange reason if i replace `$('#username').autocompleteArray('http://bucatarie/menu/add-recipe/format/html');` with `$('#username').autocompleteArray(['Jack', 'John', 'Jason', 'Jeremy', 'jimmy', 'jean']);` it works perfect. I can't seem to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Why not JSON instead of HTML context? You even don't need a view to that.

Comment: because the script is already made so i thought it would be very simple to implement using that tutorial. It works if i provide the data in the js file. Otherwise nothing happens

Comment: Have you already see the ajax response in firebug? How its look like? If you access the page in your browser (used in the ajax) you have the expected result?

Comment: it doesn't load the page at all. I see the static html with the inputs but not ajax call or response in firebug.

Comment: the libraries are loaded correctly, i know that for sure cuz i checked it using static data and it worked.

Comment: No error? No ajax call and response? Simply nothing happens? Strange... I've used this autocomplete too, the only differencente is that I'm not using contextSwitch. I've disabled layout and viewrederer in the action, and then echo the keywords with \n. We need to know where is the error first, maybe if you create a static page with the keywords you can know if the problem is with php or not.

Comment: maybe that's why...i should disable layout and viewrender

Comment: my init looks like this
public function init() {
        $this->_helper->ajaxContext()->addActionContext('add-recipe', 'html')->initContext();
        parent::init();
    }

my action looks like this:

if ($this->_helper->ajaxContext()->getCurrentContext()) {
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
            $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
            $this->view->words = array('leon', 'lionel', 'Lenny', 'Linda', 'Lindy');
        }
no change, still the same problem. I have tested the static page with the keywords, it works.it has to be from the php. donno why.

Comment: You are sure http://bucatarie/menu/add-recipe/format/html is a valid url in your setup? If you invoke it in the browser it does'nt throw a exception of some sort?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class MenuController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function addRecipeAction() {

        $words = array('leon', 'lionel', 'Lenny', 'Linda', 'Lindy');

        foreach($words as $w) echo "$w\n";

        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    }
}
```

This should work.

What's the purpose of the code bellow?

```
$recipeForm = new Application_Form_Recipe();
$recipeForm->setMethod('post');
$recipeForm->setAction('/menu/add-recipe');
$this->view->recipeForm = $recipeForm;
```

Comment: Why down vote? This code should work. The problem like was said in the comments, is with the output returned by the php. I really didn't understand...